# How to display content in view pager with sliding tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-cursorloader

I am trying to implement an article viewer, which, at first, will display a list of articles divided by category with the use of sliding tabs and a ViewPager.

I am pulling the articles from a server and am trying to load them to the UI via a ContentProvider and a CursorLoader.

In order to implement the aforementioned structure I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) which uses tabs with a ViewPager.

Here is the point of interest:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.article_list,
                container, false);
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent1.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 1);
                getActivity().startService(intent1);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent2.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 2);
                getActivity().startService(intent2);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent3.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 3);
                getActivity().startService(intent3);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent4.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 4);
                getActivity().startService(intent4);
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent intent5 = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleService.class);
                intent5.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 5);
                getActivity().startService(intent5);
                break;
        }

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }
```

As you can see I am creating a different request that corresponds to a different article category and I intend for the resulting content for each tab to be displayed in a ListView. The plan is to set the CursorAdapter to that ListView but I've never worked with sliding tabs before. How will I go about implementing that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make bit more clear?

Comment: @Anitha Gladly, but what should I elaborate on?